# Future perfect with 'by' and 'on'

Tags: grammar, sentence-construction, sentence-meaning

What's the difference between the following

1.You will have received it by Monday.

2.On Monday, you will have already received it.

What is the difference between the two? To me both are different ways of telling the same thing.

Thank you

Comment: By moving *Monday* to the front you're placing more emphasis on the specific day (which might be more appropriate if the preceding conversation focuses on specific days). Including the word *already* also places more emphasis on the idea that you'll receive it *before* Monday (otherwise the other person might suppose that it *could* arrive sometime on Monday, rather than having been already delivered before that day starts).

Comment: @FumbleFingers does #1 mean that the latest time one can receive is including Monday and no later than the midnight on Monday. Am I right?

Comment: People will have different opinions on whether ***by Monday*** implies delivery will be some time *before* Monday, or anywhen up to and including all (or part of) Monday. That's why hard-pressed developers like to use this form, because it gives them a bit more "wiggle room"  (and also why I said *the other person **might** suppose* a later delivery). If the *customer* wants to clarify, he'll end up asking something like *Do you mean **first thing** Monday, or perhaps sometime after I've left work (which will be too late)?*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many differences between the sentences. Let's go through a few.

> You will have received it by Monday.

The thing that's tricky about this sentence is that it has the [future perfect](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/3657/when-should-i-use-would-would-have-will-and-will-have) tense (i.e. suggesting actions that will be done, but [haven't been done yet](https://learnenglish.britishcouncil.org/en/english-grammar/verbs/modal-verbs/will-have-or-would-have), but should (ideally) be completed within a certain time frame).

It means that someone promised you you'd receive it by Monday, and he's already thinking about what happens after that point. The 'by' here makes it tricky too by implying "at least, at no later than, not after," and as a result, means that you can start working on something else or be expectant of other conditions that arise due to its arrival.

> On Monday, you will have already received it.

This implies that when Monday happens (it hasn't happened yet, but it will), it will be there. It specifies the range of time which could be long down to a small one, suggesting that someone has done their work ahead of time, and therefore you are able to receive it by the time Monday happens.

If you want to read more on this subject, I suggest the following two websites:

- [ESLCafe (Grammar lessons: Prepositions #2)](http://www.eslcafe.com/grammar/prepositions02.html)
- [EpressoEnglish (Prepositions of Time)](https://www.espressoenglish.net/prepositions-of-time-in-english/)

Comment: "It means that someone promised you you'd receive it by Monday, and he's already thinking about what happens after that point." So here the point from where the sentence is looked upon is either the midnight of Monday or sometime later than that. Right?